# How to left-align the caption of a table in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I am trying to insert a table and left align it. The table has a caption, which of course, I want to be left-aligned. However, for some reason, the caption stays centered:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{graphicx, import}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Table Analysis}
\begin{table}
    \raggedright
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline 
        \textbf{Data}\\
        \hline
        1061.5 \\
        1384.7 \\
        1350.5 \\
        ...    \\
        1021.9 \\
        1097.3 \\
        1291.6 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption of Table.}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I cannot change the `\captionsetup` , because I don't want all my captions in the presentation to be left-aligned. If, for example, the figure is centered, I want my caption to be centered as well. Only in this case, I want the table to be left-aligned.

Comment: Off-topic, but you do not need `graphicx` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `caption` package and use of the `justification` and `singlelinecheck` options as given in this answer. Also, in `\captionsetup` you could select the `table` option explicitly.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx, import}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Table Analysis}
\begin{table}
    \raggedright
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline 
        \textbf{Data}\\
        \hline
        1061.5 \\
        1384.7 \\
        1350.5 \\
        ...    \\
        1021.9 \\
        1097.3 \\
        1291.6 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption of Table.}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Center figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Center figure}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

to get

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In beamer the table environment does little more than centering the table. So if you don't want to centre the table, simply don't put it in a table environment.

If you like the caption to look the same you can either manually write "Table: " (as in my answer) or use the `\captionof` macro from the `caption` package (which is explained in the [answer by Raaja](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447526/36296))

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{
%graphicx, 
import}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Table Analysis}
%\begin{table}
%    \raggedright
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline 
        \textbf{Data}\\
        \hline
        1061.5 \\
        1384.7 \\
        1350.5 \\
        ...    \\
        1021.9 \\
        1097.3 \\
        1291.6 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

{\usebeamercolor*[fg]{caption name}Table:} Caption of Table.
%\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

And just for completeness because you say that you cannot use `\captionsetup`:

If you use it within a group it won't affect other tables or figures

```
{
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\begin{table}
\caption{Caption of Table.}
\end{table}
}
```